# JBOSS 5 Auto deployment of mbeans In JMX server-ISSUE using HTTP url

Tags: jboss, jmx

In JBoss 4.x i used to deploy *.sar files via JMX server  .I use server.invoke(new ObjectName("jboss.system:service=MainDeployer"),"deploy",new Object[]{"http://"+hostname+":"+port+"/resources/jbossexample.sar"},new String[]{"java.lang.String"});

The *.sar is present in a remote location.So i used http:\.

This used to be suceessfull.In JBoss 5.x i m not able to do this .It throws up following exception.Is there any new process to be followed  in my side.Is this JBoss bug fixed in other versions?Kindly  give your suggestions.

java.io.IOException: No context factory for http://192.168.112.103:9090/resource
s/jbossagent.sar
        at org.jboss.virtual.VFS.getVFS(VFS.java:196)
        at org.jboss.virtual.VFS.getRoot(VFS.java:212)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:815)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:790)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatch
er.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.
java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.jmx.connector.invoker.InvokerAdaptorService.invoke(InvokerA
daptorService.java:270)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatch
er.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractIntercept
or.java:138)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:90)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelM
BeanOperationInterceptor.java:140)
        at org.jboss.jmx.connector.invoker.SerializableInterceptor.invoke(Serial
izableInterceptor.java:74)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:90)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.
java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPProxyFactory.invoke(JRMPProxyFac
tory.java:180)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatch
er.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.
java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPInvoker$MBeanServerAction.invoke
(JRMPInvoker.java:855)
        at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPInvoker.invoke(JRMPInvoker.java:
422)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:5
35)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTranspor
t.java:790)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport
.java:649)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
utor.java:885)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:907)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 1):

It's broken in JBoss 5 and fixed in JBoss 6.0.0.CR1

https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8319?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel